# Controller response weird behaviour

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, controller, response

I don't understand this case of json response in my Laravel Controller

Work fine, as expected :

```
public function getHelloV1(Request $req) {
    if ($isOK == false) {
         return response()->json([
             'success' => false,
             'msg' => 'hum...',
         ], 400);
     }

     return View::make('app.hello'); }
```

Does not work at all as expected :

```
private test() {
     if ($isOK == false) {
         return response()->json([
             'success' => false,
             'msg' => 'hum...',
         ], 400);
     }}

public function getHelloV2(Request $req) {
     self::test();

     return View::make('app.hello');}
```

For the getHelloV2, the private test() is correctly reached (a simple Log::debug() confirms it) but the json response will not be triggered

Anyone knows why please? Just to understand...

FYI: I also tried with `Response::json([...], 400);` but same behaviors...

Answer (score 0):

In your second example you return the response in your private function but you don't store it anywhere to display it.

In your first example you access directly your public function so your response is being handled and displayed but that's not the case in your second example.

```
public function getHelloV2(Request $req) {
     self::test();

     return View::make('app.hello');
}
```

`self:test();`  will reach to your private function test but you need to send variable there. `$isOk` variable is not defined anywhere in your private function so you need to define it inside your `getHelloV2` and send it to test something like:

```
public function getHelloV2(Request $req) {
     $isOk = false;
     self::test($isOk);

     return View::make('app.hello');
}
```

And your private function should be something like:

```
private test($isOK) {
     if ($isOK == false) {
         return response()->json([
             'success' => false,
             'msg' => 'hum...',
         ], 400);
     }}
```

If this value is coming from a request just pass the request field in order to check it.

Now in your public function `getHelloV2` you have the output of test, you just need to store it and display it somewhere like:

```
public function getHelloV2(Request $req) {
     $myOutput = self::test();

     echo $myOutput; //here is your json response
     return View::make('app.hello');
}
```

The best practise would be to return something outside of your if check also so your function always outputs something. You can just return a boolean value but your function should return something if `$isOk` is true.

Comment: I understand what you explain but it confuses me a little bit on one point.

why does the return of a json response need to be echo and not the return of a view?

if we replace the return of the json response with a return of a View::make() it works well so why ?

From my understanding, it's also a return.

I just want to factor few particular case in my controller. Not enough to make a middleware, but enough to factor it (I guess)

Comment: or we can even replace with a `return redirect()->route()`... it works well

I do not understand why the `return response()->json()` does not work :/

Comment: Because redirect and response is different behaviour. Redirect will load a view for you and send you there, response will just print a message, but in your case this message is the output of a private function called in your public function. The message is there, you are just not doing anything with it. Read my answer till the end.

Comment: I have read till the end and I thank you for your time to explain it to me =)

the problem, and surely because of my misunderstanding, is also about the echo...

In your last example, you echo the $myOutput wich is the return of the private self::test() and this wont also trigger a json response...

As said, I am learning laravel/php and I just want to understand ^^

Thank you in any case for your time